# Should a One-to-One mapping let me add more entries?

Tags: jhipster

When creating a One-to-One mapping from another entity to the Jhipster generated user entity, should I be allowed to add more in the dashboard?

An example would be: 
OneToOne: 
Blog{user} to User

A user should have only one blog, or should not be allowed to add more than one blog. However, using the entities as generated by JHipster, a user can add many Blogs even though the relationship is One-to-One.

Answer (score 1):

If you created a OneToOne relationship between entities, each entity can only have one relationship between the two.  While the entities may appear in the dropdown, attempting to create a second relationship to the same entity should fail due to SQL constraints.

To only display entities without an existing OneToOne relationships, you would need to add a custom query to return just those entities.  There's a related issue tracking this feature [here](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/6735).

Comment: Thanks! I guess we'll just have to see when this gets merged and released in a later version.